# Wrap line of text in div, depending on the first symbol

Tags: php

Ok i have some .txt file which looks something like this.

```
+ Some text
~ Some text
    ~ more text
    ~ more text
    - more text
- and some text here
```

I want to wrap every line in new div, but if line begins with + to add class 'add', for - to add class 'removed', and for ~ to add class 'edit';

My current code is

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$out = '';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!empty($line)) {
        if ($line[0] == "+") {
            $out .= "<div class='add'>$line</div>";
        }
        elseif ($line[0] == "-") {
            $out .= "<div class='removed'>$line</div>";
        }
        elseif ($line[0] == "~") {
            $out .= "<div class='edit'>$line</div>";
        }
        elseif ($line[0] == "\t") {
            if ($line[1] == "+") {
                $out .= "<div class='add'>$line</div>";
            }
            elseif ($line[1] == "-") {
                $out .= "<div class='removed'>$line</div>";
            }
            elseif ($line[1] == "~") {
                $out .= "<div class='edit'>$line</div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does the job but I would like a more elegant solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array like this:

```
$cssClass = array('+' => 'add', '-' => 'remove', '~' => 'edit');
```

and then

```
$out .= "<div class='".$cssClass[$line[0]]."'>$line</div>";
```

without if or switch.

Comment: smarter way than switch or if

Comment: yea but some lines start with "\t" so you need to add extra more line like diEcho $line = ($line[0] == "\t") ? $line[1] : $line[0];

Comment: @NemanjaLazic `$lines = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $text));`

Comment: @billyonecan yes, but I really need to keep the \t tags.
`$cssClass = array('+' => 'add', '-' => 'remove', '~' => 'edit');
   $sym = ($line[0] == "\t") ? $line[1] : $line[0];
   $out .= "<div class='".$cssClass[$sym]."'>$line</div>";`

Answer (score 1):

you can try [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
  $line = ($line[0] == "\t") ? $line[1] : $line[0];
  switch($line){ 
     case '+' : $class="add" ; break;
     case '~' : $class="edit" ; break;
     case '-' : $class="removed"; break;
     default  : $class="";
    }
 $out .= "<div class='$class'>$line</div>";
```